# Symfony2 (doctrine2) : How to create universal method updateOrCreate?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do something like (if it possible)

```
function updateOrCreate($obj,$findOneBy) {

    // not sure if it will work
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(get_class($obj)); 
    if ($object = $repo->findOneBy($findOneBy)) {
        // how to replace $object by $obj and persist it?
    } else { 
        $em->persist($obj);
    }
    $em->flush();

}
```

Any ideas?

upd: If entity found, then I need to update him, else I need to create new entity.

Comment: This question isn't clear at least to me. What are you trying to obtain? Please update your quesiton with more details (not code ones but concept ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need logic, doctrine take care about update/insert logic for you.
You try to fetch entity from DB. If it was found, you can modify it; any persist operation will result in update operation. If entity isn't found, you have to create a brand new one and then persist it; this will result creation operation.

As easy ad this!

Comment: That's all I wanted to hear. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(null==$obj->getId()) {
    $em->persist($obj);
}
$em->flush();
```

That's all you need I think.

However when you don't already know at this point if your entity is already persisted you're certainly violating the single responsibility principle in your code.